# Appending <a> into <li> trouble

Tags: jquery, ajax, append

I am simply trying to append an a-tag into a li, but for some reason I cannot see why this doesn't work.

```
navListItem = '<li class="p-list-item"></li>';                
mainLink = '<a class="main-a" href="' + item.link + '"><span>"' + item.title + '"</span></a>'; 
$(navListItem).append(mainLink);
```

Comment: It seems to be working just fine, but what exactly are you expecting, you're not inserting any of the elements into the DOM ?

Answer (score 3):

You need something to append it to

```
var item = {
    link:"javascript:void(0)",
    title: "title"
};
navListItem = '<li class="p-list-item"></li>';                
mainLink = '<a class="main-a" href="' + item.link + '"><span>"' + item.title + '"</span></a>';
var z = $(navListItem).append(mainLink);

$("#container").append(z);
```

here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6vy5efeu/

Answer (score 1):

Your navListItem does not exist yet.

append it to another html element first and change the last line to:

```
$(".p-list-item").append(mainLink);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems legit and work for me.

Did you append the navListItem to a real html-element in the DOM?

```
$(document.body).append(navListItem);
```